# Преобразования относительно точки

Tags: математика, матрицы

Не могу понять, как осуществлять трансформацию с помощью матриц относительно некоторой точки.

Предположим есть двумерная сцена и вью для нее. Вью имеет размеры `{width, height}` и имеет привязку к сцене в верхнем левом углу, так что позиция сцены там будет `{x, y}`. Таким образом можно получить матрицу

```
1 0 x
0 1 y
0 0 1
```

с помощью которой из вью можно получить прямоугольник сцены, который отображается во вью из разменров вью. Теперь, предположим, мы решили увеличить изображение в два раза

```
2 0 x
0 2 y
0 0 1
```

Таким образом изображение действительно увеличится в два раза, но мы будем видеть верхнюю-левую четверть, а не центр изображения до увеличения. Понятно, что для корректного увеличения нужно передать анкор, но я не совсем понимаю как я должен его использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прелесть представления аффинных трансформаций матрицами в том, что разные трансформации можно очень легко и чисто механически комбинировать: для этого нужно просто перемножить матрицы. Пусть есть две матрицы, переноса на (x, y) и масштабирования относительно центра в N раз:

```
    1 0 x        N 0 0
T = 0 1 y    S = 0 N 0
    0 0 1        0 0 1
```

Тогда трансформация масштабирования относительно другого центра получается последовательностью действий: переносом в выбранную точку, масштабированием и обратным переносом, что равносильно перемножению матриц *Q*=*T⋅S⋅T<sup>-1</sup>*, где *T<sup>-1</sup>* — обратная матрица переноса

```
    / 1 0 x \   / N 0 0 \   / 1  0 -x \   / N 0 N(1-x) \
T = | 0 1 y | ⋅ | 0 N 0 | ⋅ | 0  1 -y | = | 0 N N(1-y) |
    \ 0 0 1 /   \ 0 0 1 /   \ 0  0  1 /   \ 0 0    1   /
```